# how moving a body with andengine?

Tags: position, sprite, andengine

I move a body in andengine and regained its position as in X, Y

and use:

`Get Position:`

`body.getPosition().x;`

`AnimatedSprite.getX();`

`Set Position:`

`Sprite.setPosition(x,y);`

but none served me.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what your problem is, the method you are looking for is `Body.setTransform(float x, float y, float angle)`. Remember that the Body coordinates are in meters, so you have to divide the pixel value by your `PIXEL_TO_METER_RATIO` (usually 32).

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in registerUpdateHandler in method onUpdate.

Example:

```
body.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

@Override
    public void reset() {

    }

    @Override
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            body.getPosition();
            body.setPosition();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

yourBody.setTransform(new Vector2(x/32,y/32), 0);

this question is the same as 
[how to move body of sprite using andEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798731/how-to-move-body-of-sprite-using-andengine)