# Andengine: PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody is creating a square body.. why?

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I'm using this to create a player body

```
private void addPlayer(){ 
        // viral -- add player
        final float startX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mPlayerTextureRegion
                .getWidth()) / 2;
        final float startY = CAMERA_HEIGHT + 100;
        this.playerFace = new Sprite(startX, startY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion,
                this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        this.playerBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld,
                playerFace, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
        final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(playerFace);
        playerFace.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);
        playerBody.setBullet(true);

        playerFaceHalfWidth = playerFace.getWidth() / 2;
        playerFaceHalfHeight = playerFace.getHeight() / 2;

        this.mScene.attachChild(playerFace);
        playerFace.setY(CAMERA_HEIGHT - playerFaceHalfHeight * 2);
    }
```

This is how I'm detecting collision with other sprites:

```
protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                if (playerFace.collidesWith(this)) {
                    // safe of touching border - else game over
                    if (!isPlayerInSafeZone()) {
                        Log.w("cd", "Game Over");
                        isGameInProgress = false;
                        mScene.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                        processLevelEnd();
                    }
                }
            };
```

The issue now is that even though i've added a circle body, the collision is detected with the player when the other sprites touch the corner of the png for player. it is a transparent area and the image has only a circle in it for which the body was created. Why is this happening? What is wrong in the above code?

**::Update based on Lucaz's inputs:**

This is my contactlistener

```
private ContactListener createContactListener()
{
ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
{
    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact)
    {
        final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
        final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();
        final String x1id = (String) x1.getBody().getUserData();
        final String x2id = (String) x2.getBody().getUserData();
        Log.w("cd", "x1 = " + x1id + " --- x2 = " + x2id);
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse)
    {

    }
};
return contactListener;
}
```

This is how I'm setting the user data for the player and other sprites:

Player:

```
    this.playerFace = new Sprite(startX, startY, this.mPlayerTextureRegion,
            this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    this.playerBody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld,
            playerFace, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    playerBody.setBullet(true);
    playerBody.setUserData("player");
```

other sprites (balls):

```
    body = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, face,
            BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
    body.setLinearVelocity(vector2);
    body.setBullet(true);
    body.setUserData("ball");
```

This is how i added the listener to physics world

```
this.mPhysicsWorld.setContactListener(createContactListener());
```

The listener is written to print the user data for colliding objects:

but when a sprite collides with player i get null for the player but user data for the other sprite as shown below... how to fix this?

```
x1 = null --- x2 = ball
```

Comment: After switching to ContactListner it is detecting collision between all sprites except the player .... :-( (the most important one) ... whats wrong with the way the player body/face is setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because collidesWith() method is checking collisions of sprites, and not bodies. So it checks if two sprites overlap (even if they are png images, they will stll be treated as not transparent rectangles). To check collisions between bodies there is another way:

```
private ContactListener createContactListener()
{
ContactListener contactListener = new ContactListener()
{
    @Override
    public void beginContact(Contact contact)
    {
        final Fixture x1 = contact.getFixtureA();
        final Fixture x2 = contact.getFixtureB();
    }

    @Override
    public void endContact(Contact contact)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse)
    {

    }
};
return contactListener;
}
```

Please look this simple tutorial:

http://www.matim-dev.com/handling-collisions-between-bodies.html

Comment: Thanks lukaz! I tried this and just one problem ... when i set user data for other sprite bodies i can get it in the contact listener, but when i set user data for playerbody, I always get null... any idea why? player body creation code is in the question.

Comment: Also, is getting the userdata the best way to ideantify objects? is there a better way ?

Comment: I think there is no better way, but if it helps you may have one name for all bodies of same kind (for examle all bullets from a gun may be called "bullet" and not "bullet1", bullet2" and so on). Regarding your player name, can you post how your contactlistener is build? Your actual code for this?

Comment: @Lukaz: updated the question with the code ... please take a look and let me know if i'm doing something wrong ...

Comment: now it is detecting collision between all sprites except the player .... :-( (the most important one)

Comment: are you sure you have a body behind your player sprite? does it behave like physical body? Did you try to register physicsconnector for playerbody in your physicsworld (`physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(sprite, body, true, true));`)?

Comment: yes i registered a physics connector as : `this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(playerFace,
    playerBody, false, true));`  Here when i keep update position to false player moves as expected. But if i set update position to true, the movement of player shows up but then player disappears. Also the collidesWith stuff would not work when true. Works fine when false.

Comment: one more thing... you said that it doesnt show the name of username of player body, but it still shows null on contact?

Comment: no, it was happening earlier, but with the code given above, it does not even detect contact with player. Detects it for every other sprite (with remaining sprites except player). There is some silly mistake with the player setup that I'm not being able to figure out.

Comment: What I mean that at some point you could see that the susername was null? It could only happen when contact hapened.

Comment: may be it was some other sprite that time. I've named all sprites now and no nulls come up (only named sprites except player). Hence, player body doesn't seem to be detected. Another thing that might be important is I'm moving the player only using move modifier. does it have something to do with this?

Comment: don't think so, name you player, and try to move it by draging, we will see then

Comment: **major update:** it was because of the move modifier. I had the inital position of the  body outside of the camera region. i moved the initial position to center of the camera and it is detected. now i can see the player detected. But, **does not move the body with move modifier**. sprite moves but body remains in the initial position.

Comment: how to make the body move with the move modifier?

Comment: there was similar problem before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039528/andengine-sprite-move-pathmodifier-and-body

Comment: also you could move your sprite and try to transform your body in onManagedUpdate() of your scene, but Im not sure if its right way. box2d was not prepared this way.

Comment: Thanks Lukaz. Your inputs pointed me in the right direction and along with this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798731/how-to-move-body-of-sprite-using-andengine) I was able to fix it. Accepting your answer as it took me really close to the solution.